# Node JS ENOENT - No such a file or a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am a node.js beginner. 
I installed dependencies using bower install and npm install. Subsequently
whenever I ran the command ember serve I am getting an error below. 
I made sure that I have a howler.js installed using npm install. Same thing with rsvp.

My node.js is 4.5.0
My npm is 2.15.9

How can I troubleshoot this problem? I tried to find on Stack & Google but couldn't find any answers that could point me to solving the problem. 
Thank you.

```html
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-3cMSiSIf.tmp/0/bower_components/howler.js/dist/howler.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
    at Concat.keyForFile (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:87:20)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Concat.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:109:65)
    at /Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
    at tryCatch (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
```

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "dependencies": {
      "ember": "~2.3.1",
      "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0",
      "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
      "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
      "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
      "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
      "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
      "jquery": "1.11.3",
      "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
      "qunit": "~1.20.0",
      "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
      "firebase": "^2.1.0",
      "filesaver": "*",
      "hls.js":"*",
      "howler.js":"*"
  }
}

{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "description": "****",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {

    "ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
    "ember-bootstrap": "0.6.0",
    "ember-cli": "2.3.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^5.2.1",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.3.0",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-g-map": "0.0.13",
    "ember-hifi": "1.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-moment": "6.0.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-sortable": "1.8.1",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.2.0",
    "emberfire": "1.6.4",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "2.11.2",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.0",
    "torii": "0.6.1",
    "ui-download": "0.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, what are you trying to build? error seems a bit generic, as you can see in related questions. if possible, please provide more details.

Comment: I am building web app that is using ember.js. What else would you like to know?

Comment: the best possibility is the long path bug on windows machines, however based on your error output you could also be into a osx machine. is your box windows or osx?

Comment: It's OSX - I am not getting any other error than: 


Build error

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/januszchudzynski/Desktop/Repositories/perfectour-web-private/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-zUC1Yi78.tmp/0/bower_components/howler.js/dist/howler.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `ember-cli-build.js` file there may be you tried to include howler package.
You need to remove this below line.

```
app.import('bower_components/h‌​owler.js/dist/howler‌​.js')
```

**EDIT:**
As you are using `howler.js` through bower, so you need to mention it in `bower.json`

Comment: I searched for 'howler' keyword in entire project, but I didn't find it anywhere. The ember-cli-build.js doesn't have it either.

Comment: did you tried installing howler through bower package earlier ?. either case try check with removing `tmp` and `dist` folders. that might help..if thats not working for you then please consider posting package.json and bower.json and ember-cli-build.js file. that will help to identify issue

Comment: Adding it to the bower fixed the problem. Wow. Can you submit it as an answer?